# Proving that every cauchy sequence is bounded: Why is the set $\cal N$ internal?

Tags: proof-explanation, cauchy-sequences, nonstandard-analysis

I'm having some trouble understanding the following proof that every real Cauchy sequence is bounded:

---

Proof:

Let $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be a Cauchy sequence and suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is not bounded. Then, there exists $\sigma\in\ ^*\mathbb N_\infty$ such that $a_\sigma\not\in\ ^*\mathbb R_\flat$. Consider the set $$\mathcal{N}=\{n\in\ ^*\mathbb N:|a_\sigma - a_n|<1\}$$
then this set is an internal set. Because $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence, then $$\forall\sigma,\nu\in\ ^*\mathbb N_\infty:a_\sigma\approx a_\nu$$
This allows us to conclude that $^*\mathbb N_\infty\subseteq\cal N$. Because $\cal N$ is internal and contains infinite elements arbitrarily small, then it must have some finite element $n_1 \in \mathbb N$, but that would imply that $a_{n_1}\not\in \ ^*\mathbb R_\flat$, which is a contradiction, thus the sequence must be bounded.

---

I don't understand why the set $\cal N$ is internal. The definition the book I'm reading gave was:

A subset $A\subseteq\ ^*\mathbb R$ if there exists a sequence of subsets $(A_n)_n$ of $\mathbb R$ such that, for any number $x\equiv [(x_n)_n]$ one has that: $$x\in A\iff\{n\in \mathbb N:x_n\in A_n\}\in \cal U$$
where $\cal U$ is the ultrafilter used to construct the hyper-reals.

But I can't find any sequence of sets that satisfy this property for the set $\cal N$. Why is this set internal?

---

Disclaimer: The book I'm using to learn nonstandard analysis is not very standard, so if any of this notation is not common, let me know.

Comment: You certainly do need to explain the notation. In particular, we need to know if your sequence is indexed by standard natural numbers? And, if not, what is the index set?

Comment: yes, the sequence in indexed by the standard naturals @RobArthan

Comment: Hint: in these situations you can try picking a sequence $s_k$ so that $[s_k] = \sigma$, then setting $A_k = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} \mid |a_{s_k} - a_n| < 1\}$. Do you then have, for some $x=[x_n]$ that $x \in \mathcal{N}$ (i.e. $|a_\sigma - a_x| < 1$) whenever the condition $x_n \in A_n$ (i.e. $|a_{s_n} - a_{x_n}| < 1$ holds for a $\mathcal{U}$-large set of indices? Why / why not?

Comment: @Z.A.K., I am not sure if Eduardo got your hint.  Perhaps you should elaborate.

Comment: Thank you for your concern @MikhailKatz I'm still trying to wrap my head around the construction Z.A.K. suggested . I almost got it, but a more detailed explanation would indeed be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Did the book not prove yet that every Cauchy sequence in the metric space $(\mathbb{R},d_{Eu})$ converges and that every convergent sequence in said space is bounded? Try this direct proof then in lieu of your question.

Let $(a_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence. Then for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a natural number $H(\epsilon)$ such that for $m,n\geq H(\epsilon)$, $|a_n-a_m|<\epsilon$. Take $\epsilon=1$ and consider $H(1)$. For all $n\geq H(1)$, $|a_n-a_{H(1)}|<1$ (Why?). Applying the triangle inequality gives us $|a_n|<|a_{H(1)}|+1$. Since $H(1)$ is a natural number there are a finite amount of terms in $(a_n)$ that come before $a_{H(1)}$. Knowing this, we let $M=max\{|a_1|+1,|a_2|+1,...,|a_{H(1)}|+1\}$ and it will be guaranteed that the absolute value of any term of $(a_n)$ will be less than $M$. Hence, $(a_n)$ is bounded.

This should be easier to follow. Perhaps someone else can better examine the book's proof but this is the proof I was taught.

Comment: Thank you. In the last chapter, the book proved that every Cauchy sequence converges and is bounded using a mix of standard and nonstandard arguments. In this chapter, after introducing internal sets, the author gave this example using only nonstandard arguments

Comment: @X, your *answer* does not answer the *question*.  The question was specific to infinitesimal analysis, namely to know why the set  $\mathcal N$ is internal, in reference to the infinitesimal definition of a Cauchy sequence (any pair of terms with nonstandard indices are infinitely close to each other).  Your *answer* does not relate to that at all.